# Integrate React app created with create-react-app into an external application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I'm using [create-react-app-typescript](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) to create a react application. What I'm trying to do is to `build` the application, then include the resulting `js` and `CSS` files into another application (which is a very old application that doesn't know anything about React or any new JavaScript features)

My problem: I want to be able to pass information to my React application; for example, I want to specify an array to be used to display information, but the issue is that as soon as I add a `<script>` tag to React's `js` file, it will try to create the application under the target `div` element.

Not sure if it's a good idea, but I try to avoid `eject`ing my React application as much as possible so that I wouldn't need to maintain everything myself.

One solution that I thought of was to create an item in `localStorage` and then read it from my React app, and this somehow solves the issue, but is this a good way to do it?

And then there's another issue: I want to be able to pass a callback from the external application to be called from my React app to cause something to happen in my external application, and this cannot be done using `localStorage`

Any help or tip is deeply appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: I think you might be confusing the concept of "app" and "component", which is totally reasonable since react blurs that line nicely. instead of pulling in the "app" from your create-react-app project, expose the App component to your other application. then you can call `ReactDOM.render` and pass whatever you want to your app component as props (callbacks, arrays, whatever)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on how to expose the `App` component to the outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to eject the project at all. One possible solution (maybe not the best) is just to change your `index.js` to expose your application. Thus instead of directly "rendering" the app do something like following

```
// needed imports

window.startFromOutside = function(element, callback) {
  ReactDOM.render(<ReactApp cb={callback} />, element)
}
```

That way you can bootstrap your react application from outside passing any properties you want.